# Can I do a group by on just 2 columns of 5

Tags: sql

I've got 2 SQL queries that I have unioned however there are 60 results where there is nothing in the 2nd query but the first 2 columns (supplier and supplier id) and the rest of the fields are null. The first query returns results in all columns. I want to show the first set of results for these 60 but not the second set however only the first 2 columns match? Is this possible. I'm sure I should know the answer to this!

e.g.

```
select 
    Supplier_name,
    Supplier_id,
    Bank_name,
    Bank_Branch
from suppliers,
     banks
where s=b and payables
union
select 
    Supplier_name,
    Supplier_id,
    Bank_name,
    Bank_Branch
from suppliers,
     banks
where s=b and <> payables
```

might return

```
AKD, 1234, HSBC, London
AKD, 1234, NULL, NULL
```

I don't want the 2nd row....

in addition here is the full query:

```
SELECT
    HZP.PARTY_NAME "SUPPLIER_NAME" ,
    APS.SEGMENT1 "SUPPLIER_NUMBER",
    IEB.BANK_ACCOUNT_NUM "BANK_ACCOUNT_NUMBER" ,
    IEB.BANK_ACCOUNT_NAME "BANK_ACCOUNT_NAME" ,
    HZPBANK.PARTY_NAME "BANK_NAME",
    IEB.IBAN,
    /*hzp.party_id hzp_party_id,
    APS.party_id aps_party_id,
    IEP.PAYEE_PARTY_ID IEP_PAYEE_PARTY_ID,
    hzp.party_id hzp_party_id1,
    IEP.EXT_PAYEE_ID IEP_EXT_PAYEE_ID,
    IPI.EXT_PMT_PARTY_ID IPI_EXT_PMT_PARTY_ID,
    ipi.instrument_id ipi_instrument_id,
    ieb.ext_bank_account_id,
    ieb.bank_id ieb_bank_id,
    hzpbank.party_id hzpbank_party_id,*/
    ibb.eft_swift_code,
    ibb.bank_branch_name,
    'Supplier' Record_type,
    HZP.country
FROM HZ_PARTIES HZP ,
    AP_SUPPLIERS APS ,
    IBY_EXTERNAL_PAYEES_ALL IEP ,
    IBY_PMT_INSTR_USES_ALL IPI ,
    IBY_EXT_BANK_ACCOUNTS IEB ,
    HZ_PARTIES HZPBANK,
    iby_ext_bank_branches_v IBB
WHERE HZP.PARTY_ID = APS.PARTY_ID
    --AND hzpbank.party_id = IBB.bank_party_id(+)
    AND IEP.PAYEE_PARTY_ID = HZP.PARTY_ID(+)
    AND IEP.EXT_PAYEE_ID = IPI.EXT_PMT_PARTY_ID(+)
    AND IPI.INSTRUMENT_ID = IEB.EXT_BANK_ACCOUNT_ID(+)
    AND IEB.BANK_ID = HZPBANK.PARTY_ID(+)
    AND IEP.PARTY_SITE_ID IS NULL
    AND IEP.ORG_ID IS NULL 
    AND IEP.ORG_TYPE IS NULL 
    AND IEP.SUPPLIER_SITE_ID IS NULL 
    --and hzp.party_name like 'RDF C%'
    AND ipi.payment_function = 'PAYABLES_DISB'
    --AND hzp.party_name = 'AKD'
    AND HZP.country = 'NL'
    AND ieb.branch_id = ibb.branch_party_id(+)

union

SELECT
    HZP.PARTY_NAME "SUPPLIER_NAME" ,
    APs.segment1 "SUPPLIER_NUMBER",
    NULL "BANK_ACCOUNT_NUMBER" ,
    NULL "BANK_ACCOUNT_NAME" ,
    NULL "BANK_NAME",
    NULL "IBAN",
    /*hzp.party_id hzp_party_id,
    APS.party_id aps_party_id,
    IEP.PAYEE_PARTY_ID IEP_PAYEE_PARTY_ID,
    hzp.party_id hzp_party_id1,
    IEP.EXT_PAYEE_ID IEP_EXT_PAYEE_ID,
    IPI.EXT_PMT_PARTY_ID IPI_EXT_PMT_PARTY_ID,
    ipi.instrument_id ipi_instrument_id,
    ieb.ext_bank_account_id,
    ieb.bank_id ieb_bank_id,
    hzpbank.party_id hzpbank_party_id,*/
    NULL "eft_swift_code",
    NULL "bank_branch_name",
    'Supplier' Record_type,
    HZP.country
FROM HZ_PARTIES HZP ,
    AP_SUPPLIERS APS ,
    IBY_EXTERNAL_PAYEES_ALL IEP ,
    IBY_PMT_INSTR_USES_ALL IPI ,
    IBY_EXT_BANK_ACCOUNTS IEB ,
    HZ_PARTIES HZPBANK,
    iby_ext_bank_branches_v IBB
WHERE HZP.PARTY_ID = APS.PARTY_ID
    --AND hzpbank.party_id = IBB.bank_party_id(+)
    AND IEP.PAYEE_PARTY_ID = HZP.PARTY_ID(+)
    AND IEP.EXT_PAYEE_ID = IPI.EXT_PMT_PARTY_ID(+)
    AND IPI.INSTRUMENT_ID = IEB.EXT_BANK_ACCOUNT_ID(+)
    AND IEB.BANK_ID = HZPBANK.PARTY_ID(+)
    AND IEP.PARTY_SITE_ID IS NULL
    AND IEP.ORG_ID IS NULL 
    AND IEP.ORG_TYPE IS NULL 
    AND IEP.SUPPLIER_SITE_ID IS NULL 
    --and hzp.party_name like 'RDF C%'
    --AND ipi.payment_function = 'PAYABLES_DISB'
    --AND hzp.party_name = 'AKD'
    AND HZP.country = 'NL'
    AND ieb.branch_id = ibb.branch_party_id(+)
```

Comment: Can you provide your actual queries please? Also, which DBMS are you using; SQL Server, MySQL, etc?

Comment: i think you must be talking about an outer join.

Comment: You probably want to put the whole thing in a subselect and add WHERE Bank_name IS NOT NULL

Answer (score 0):

First of all -- if you don't want the results from the 2nd query, then why UNION it to the first?

But if you have no control over that then you can do something like this:

```
SELECT
   ...
   ...
FROM
   (
      SELECT query 1
      UNION
      SELECT query 2
   ) a
WHERE
   field 3 is NOT NULL
   AND field 4 is NOT NULL
```

Comment: Its Oracle R12, the table setup is a bit weird but heres my query:

Comment: ahhhh too long by 2112 characters!

Comment: have put into my original post, basically customers and suppliers are in the same table so I want a list of all suppliers with bank accounts but also those without. the first query gets those with and the 2nd those without but it also brings back the ones with again as null fields. I'm sure this is a rookie mistake :-)

Comment: @user3245361 -- I'm not going to read through all that.  The best advice I can give you is 1) run each individual SELECT by itself to find the one(s) that are giving you records that you don't want, and then 2) use the WHERE clause of THAT query to filter those unwanted records out.